# Creating re-usable ACF fields that can be inside various elements/classes

Tags: php

I have the following code which is inside its own file, which gets an ACF field and outputs it.

```
<?=get_field('text') ?>
```

I then include this in another template file using PHP include, meaning I have re-usable fields throughout my site. This has worked well in the past, as I can create consistent 'text' fields such as: `<h1>My Text field</h1>`

However, I'd like to further extend this by writing some kind of fucntion that allows me to call the PHP include, whilst also assigning the container tag (h1,h2 etc), as well as optional classes:

`<h1>My Text field</h1>`

`<h2>My Text field</h2>`

`<p>My Text field</p>`

`<h1 class="myClass">My Text field</h1>`

Is this possible?

Comment: Have tried anything to accomplish your idea?

Comment: Not sure where to start unfortunately

Comment: show your `get_field()` method.

Comment: That's it, above. That part is very simple, it's the creation of reusable includes that is the issue

Comment: Take a look on my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<?php

class functions{
    public static function get_field($text = 'Default', $tag = 'p', $class = false){
        if($class){
           $class = ' class="' . $class . '"'; 
        }
        return '<' . $tag . $class . '>' . $text . '</' . $tag . '>';
    }
}

echo functions::get_field('My Text', 'h1', 'my-class');
?>
```

in HTML

```html
<h1 class="my-class">My Text</h1>
```

Hope it will give you an idea on how to expand this method.

Comment: Thank you - this certainly set me in the right direction!